# could not find function "as.party.Weka_tree"

Tags: r, function, package, party

I'm struggling with an error message that I don't understand. I'm doing some decision trees and everything goes fine, until I try to plot it

```
plot(as.party.Weka_tree(CostSensitive_Tree))
```

which gives this error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': could not find function "as.party.Weka_tree"
```

I checked multiple times with `help.search("as.party.Weka_tree")`and the  package (
partykit) is installed, what could be the cause of this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you attach the package with `library`? What happens if you refer to it directly with the package name: `partykit::as.party.Weka_tree`?

Comment: I definitely forgot to add "library partykit"..... thank you! Sometimes the simplest answers are the right ones

Comment: Please also accept the answer given below so that the question is flagged as being resolved here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure that the package is loaded, i.e., `library("partykit")`. Second, you should not call the S3 method directly but just say `as.party(CostSensitive_Tree)`. Internally the `as.party()` generic function then dispatches to the `as.party.Weka_tree()` method but the latter should not be called directly.